# How to generate and use login action token for Keycloak user update profile in external mail template

Tags: keycloak, user-management, keycloak-rest-api

Our backend is currently using the KeyCloak Admin Client API (Java) to

- Create users
- Create roles
- Assign roles to users
- Executing actions emails (“UPDATE_PASSWORD”, “UPDATE_PROFILE”, “VERIFY_EMAIL”)

Our flow however needs to support the following scenario :

- Instead of using the `executeActionsEmail` API call and have Keycloak send out an email to  users for them to complete their profile we would like to use an external email service / template to send out these mails
- When Keycloak sends out an `UPDATE_PROFILE` email it contains a `/login-actions/action-token?key=eyJhbG…` link with an action-token.
- We would like to embed this link into our own email templates (outside of keycloak)

So the questions is can I use the KeyCloak API (or some other mechanism) to generate login actions URLs for a user inside a keycloak realm that we can then use in an external email template to send out a complete registration email ?

Comment: did you find away around this? Im facing a similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement custom service providers by implementing a particular service provider interface. For your case, you could implement a custom resource provider that returns an action token based on some input parameters.

Implementation instructions for a custom REST API endpoint are provided in the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_extensions_rest). You can also check [this article](https://www.janua.fr/action-token-in-keycloak/), that pretty much covers your scenario.

I played around with it a bit, here's an example:

```
public class ExecuteActionsTokenResourceProvider implements RealmResourceProvider {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ExecuteActionsTokenResourceProvider.class);

    private final KeycloakSession session;

    public ExecuteActionsTokenResourceProvider(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("action-tokens")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response getActionToken(
        @QueryParam("userId") String userId,
        @QueryParam("email") String email,
        @QueryParam("redirectUri") String redirectUri,
        @QueryParam("clientId") String clientId,
        @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

        KeycloakContext context = session.getContext();
        RealmModel realm = context.getRealm();
        int validityInSecs = realm.getActionTokenGeneratedByUserLifespan();
        int absoluteExpirationInSecs = Time.currentTime() + validityInSecs;

        ClientModel client = assertValidClient(clientId, realm);

        assertValidRedirectUri(redirectUri, client);

        // Can parameterize this as well
        List requiredActions = new LinkedList();
        requiredActions.add(RequiredAction.UPDATE_PASSWORD.name());

        String token = new ExecuteActionsActionToken(
            userId,
            absoluteExpirationInSecs,
            requiredActions,
            redirectUri,
            clientId
        ).serialize(
            session,
            context.getRealm(),
            uriInfo
        );

        return Response.status(200).entity(token).build();
    }

    private void assertValidRedirectUri(String redirectUri, ClientModel client) {
        String redirect = RedirectUtils.verifyRedirectUri(session, redirectUri, client);
        if (redirect == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(
                ErrorResponse.error("Invalid redirect uri.", Status.BAD_REQUEST));
        }
    }

    private ClientModel assertValidClient(String clientId, RealmModel realm) {
        ClientModel client = realm.getClientByClientId(clientId);
        if (client == null) {
            log.debugf("Client %s doesn't exist", clientId);
            throw new WebApplicationException(
                ErrorResponse.error("Client doesn't exist", Status.BAD_REQUEST));
        }
        if (!client.isEnabled()) {
            log.debugf("Client %s is not enabled", clientId);
            throw new WebApplicationException(
                    ErrorResponse.error("Client is not enabled", Status.BAD_REQUEST));
        }
        return client;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getResource() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // Nothing to close.
    }
}
```

You would then package this class in a JAR and deploy it to Keycloak, like described in the deployment documentation. There are also lots of examples of this [on Github](https://github.com/doughtnerd/keycloak-custom-spi-example/blob/master/Dockerfile).

Comment: I tried to replicate this in my local keyclaok, but when tried to access the API from postman, its returning 404 Not Found error. I have posted this here Can you please check this?... 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76869266/custom-api-in-keycloak-is-returning-http-404-not-found