# Custom API in Keycloak is returning HTTP 404 Not Found

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have created my Own custom API to generate the action-token from Keycloak. When I hit the my custom API from Postman it's giving HTTP 404 Not Found.

I'm using **Keycloak version 20.0.2**

Below is my Implementation approach,

ProviderFactory class

```
public class ActionTokenProviderFactory implements RealmResourceProviderFactory {

    public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "custom-action-token";
    // Logger
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActionTokenProviderFactory.class);

    @Override
    public ActionTokenProvider create(KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
        log.info("ActionTokenProviderFactory create()");
        return new ActionTokenProvider(keycloakSession);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope scope) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory keycloakSessionFactory) {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }
}
```

Provider class

```
public class ActionTokenProvider implements RealmResourceProvider {

    // Logger
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActionTokenProvider.class);
    private final KeycloakSession keycloakSession;
    public ActionTokenProvider(KeycloakSession keycloakSession){
        this.keycloakSession=keycloakSession;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("generate-action-tokens")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response getActionToken(@QueryParam("userId") String userId,
                                   @QueryParam("email") String email,
                                   @QueryParam("redirectUri") String redirectUri,
                                   @QueryParam("clientId") String clientId,
                                   @Context UriInfo uriInfo){
        log.info("ActionTokenProvider getActionToken() ::: "+userId+", "+email+", "+", "+clientId);
        KeycloakContext keycloakContext = keycloakSession.getContext();
        RealmModel realm = keycloakContext.getRealm();
        int accessTokenLifespan = realm.getAccessTokenLifespan();
        int absoluteExpirationInSecs = Time.currentTime() + accessTokenLifespan;
        log.info("ActionTokenProvider getActionToken() absoluteExpirationInSecs ::: "+absoluteExpirationInSecs);

        List<String> requiredActions=new LinkedList<>();
        requiredActions.add(UserModel.RequiredAction.UPDATE_PASSWORD.name());

        String token = new ExecuteActionsActionToken(
                userId, absoluteExpirationInSecs, requiredActions, redirectUri, clientId)
                .serialize(keycloakSession, keycloakContext.getRealm(), uriInfo);
        log.info("ActionTokenProvider getActionToken() token ::: "+token);

        return Response.status(200).entity(token).build();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getResource() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
```

**src\main\resources\META-INF\services**

File name : `org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProviderFactory`
File contetn : `com.event.actiontoken.provider.ActionTokenProviderFactory`

Using the above stuff I have build my Project and copy the JAR file under **\target** folder and paste it into **Keycloak standalone deployments** folder.

This **\standalone\deployments** was not exists in my Keyclaok directory, So I created this manually and paste the JAR file here.

This is my directory structure **keycloak-20.0.2\standalone\deployments**

And then I tried to access my API from Postman but getting 404 error. below is the API details

```
http://localhost:8080/realms/my_realm/custom-action-token/generate-action-tokens

Query Parameters
    userId:055b07a3-9fd9-4285-88b2-34165d8f3022
    email:rck1234@gmail.com
    clientId:my_own_client
    redirectUri:http://localhost:1030/
```

For security reason I gave dummy values here, when I hit this I was getting 401 Unauthorized error, So I passed Bearer Token then its giving 404 Not Found error.

I tried with **/admin/realms/my_realm/** and **/auth/admin/realms/my_realm/** also, but its returning same response.

Did I miss anything here or Do I need to configure anything Keycloak to make it work?

Help me on this.